# Copy & insert row with formulas in protected sheet

Tags: vba

I want to insert a row that is copied from above line with formulas in it by double click. and when I turned on protect worksheet macro is not working. I tried the method of `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1"` but it is not working. Could any of you guide me what my mistake is and what the solution is?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1"
If [BusinessType] = "Operating Lease (Contract Based)" Then
  Range("hide").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Range("hide").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As 
Boolean)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1"

'Updateby Extendoffice 20160725

    Cancel = True
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents 
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One should be always careful when using `Worksheet_Change` event, because it gets triggered with *every* worksheet change. In this case, calling `Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert` triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event. And the last step in the event is protecting the sheet, which throws an error on the next line `Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow`. When this line of code runs, the sheet is protected, which throws an error.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Avoid using `Worksheet_Change` if possible.
2. Remove `Sheet.protect()` from the `Worksheet_Change`.
3. Disable events in the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` using `Application.EnableEvents = False`. However, i do not recommend doing this, as you have to make sure that events are enabled again (using proper error handling).